# How can I achieve below requirement in ruby?

Tags: ruby, configuration, arguments, block, metaprogramming

```
@custom_column = CustomColumns.configure :projects do |user, tag|
  columns = ModelName.method_name(user,tag)
end

@custom_column.columns should return ["title", "description"]
CustomColumns.projects.columns should return ["title", "description"]

@custom_column1 = CustomColumns.configure :groups do |domain|
  columns = ModelName.method_name(domain)
end

@custom_column1.columns should return => ["desctiption", "created_at"]
CustomColumns.groups.columns should return => ["desctiption", "created_at"]
```

I tried below code to achieve above results. But I don't know how can I pass different arguments in blocks? Or How can I achieve above results ?

```
module CustomColumns
  class Rule
      attr_accessor :column_for, :columns
  end

  class << self
    attr_accessor :rule
  end

  def self.configure(column_for, &block)
    @column_for = column_for
    @columns = block.call
  end

end
```

Comment: Well for starters it looks like your block wants arguments but you are not `yielding` any with `block.call`. e.g. in the first example it is expecting `user` and `tag` to be sent to the block and in the second example it is expecting `domain`. [Here is a quick tutorial on  Yielding to Blocks](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm) but there are many more available. Once you understand how that works it might help you figure this out.

Comment: What I am asking is achievable or not? Or Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. `foo = bar` is *always* interpreted as assigning to a local variable. It will never call the `foo=` setter. You must provide an explicit receiver.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to achieve this? What is the best and preferred way to handle above the scenario?

Comment: It's not clear what "the above scenario" is. You dumped a bunch of code with no explanation, and asked whether one can make that code run, and the answer is no. If you want to know whether one can design that differently, you first have to explain what "that" is.